# Using TinyMCE in Yii conflicting with JQuery

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, tinymce

I created a tinyMCE widget for my Yii Form as shown by the code below,

```
 $this->widget('application.extensions.tinymce.ETinyMce',
      array(
           'model'=>$model,
           'attribute'=>'labExaminationDetails',
           'editorTemplate'=>'full',
           'htmlOptions'=>array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50, 'class'=>'tinymce')      
      )
);
```

Although it works perfectly and inserts records to the database too, the JQuery used on my menu bar does not function because of this. If I remove this widget, then the menu bar works correctly.

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors? TinyMCE should be compatible with jquery.

Comment: no, there are no errors in any part

Comment: Other jquery code does work? Can you post some menu bar code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/U4B8UXHZ

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it. TinyMCE in jquery version is not compatible with bootstrap menu. Workaround is to use non-jquery tineMCE. Check issue here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3620

Comment: thnx, but i couldnt find a non jquery version of tinycme and the question you posted mentions to remove the jquery link from the footer and give a new link at the top. But it too doesnt fix the problam

Comment: By default TineMCE is not using jQuery, yii extension uses jQuery version of TinyMCE. You should replace TinyMCE shipped with ETinyMce with non-jquery version. Only difference with versions of TinyMCE is that jQuery version is slightly smaller.

Comment: i strongly advise everyone not to use the jQuery tinymce version, it is slow due to the object creation overhead. It is better to load tiny_mce.js and jQuery seperatly on the page.

Comment: I had a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getFullYear'` error on page after loading html via ajax and reinitiating datetimepicker on a text field. It took about two hours  for me to understand that the problem is related to using TinyMCE on the same page.